# Xcode Crash when i open A specific project

Tags: ios, xcode

I was working on a project and I am using Xcode 8.3.3. I have also installed  Xcode 9 beta in my machine. Yesterday Xcode was completely fine but today when I try to first open Xcode after a few seconds it crashes. I don't understand what's wrong. One thing I tested is that my other project opens completely fine but when I try open my working project thats when it happens.

Here is the error:

```
    Time Awake Since Boot: 1500 seconds

     System Integrity Protection: enabled

     Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

     Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
     Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
     Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

     Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8E3004b
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-12175.1/IDEKit/Editor/IDEEditorGeniusMode.m:730
Details:  nil != structureRootNavigableItem, domainIdentifier:Xcode.IDEKit.NavigableItemDomain.SwiftSourceInterface
Object:   <IDEEditorGeniusMode: 0x7fef5b98a060>
Method:   -_resetManualCategoryNavigableItemForEditorContext:toDomainWithIdentifier:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fef54e03230>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   

Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
```

There is also lots of lines after that.

Comment: If you have time to do so before crash, press option + clean. You should report the crash to Apple.

Comment: You're mentioning 2 Xcode versions. Can you clarify which one did you use that caused the crash?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` directory, just in case the problem is something in reinstantiating Xcode's previous indexing of your source code?

Comment: https://bugreporter.apple.com is where to post this. Not Stack Overflow.

Comment: 8.3.3 Xcode versions crash

Comment: i am not able to open any kind of project

Comment: Please check this might be helpful  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8818